# How do I launch a react js. app in full screen on windows?

Tags: reactjs, fullscreen

I am building a react app for a kiosk with a windows operating system.

The app is supposed to appear as full screen (F11 look) right when it launches (without clicking any buttons).

I saw that as of a few years ago chrome does not support full screen launch. Has there been any changes with that?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately not directly. However, you can alter the shortcut to the web app by adding these two properties: `--fullscreen --kiosk`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please specify where these two properties need to be added?

Comment: yess! right click on the desktop shortcut, then properties, then destination

Comment: I don't seem to find 'Destination'
I tried editing the 'target' like this:

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --fullscreen --kiosk http://localhost:3000/

but it doesn't open the URL in a full screen mode, just a regular chrome tab